# React - Get Div Element from another Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My Objective is to make a simple open and close menu in React. Im used to vannila javascript where i can use **getElementById** to get my elements and store them in a variable, and do whatever i want whit them. Now im trying to do that whit react, but its getting a little dificult, i have try to use **ref**.

So this is my menu, i want to click on the button and hide the menu and show the content, that is my objective.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';

class Menu extends Component {

  render() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    var mobileContainer = this.refs.mobileContent1;   
    console.log(mobileContainer);
  }

    return (
      <Grid fluid>
      <div className="menuContent">
        <Row center="xs">
          <Col xs={12}>
            <span href="" className="button" onClick={handleClick}>Hello, world!</span>
          </Col>                 
        </Row>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    );
  }


}

export default Menu;
```

When i console log mobileContainer i get **this is undefined**

This is my content component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';

class MobileContent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid fluid>
        <div className="mobileContent" ref="mobileContent1">
          <Row center="xs">
            <Col xs={12}>
              <span className="button">Hello, world!</span>
              <span className="close">X</span>              
            </Col>                 
          </Row>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default MobileContent;
```

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't define your click handler `handleClick` inside the `render` function, it will get created again and again whenever your `render` is called.

Now the reason for the error is that you haven't `bind` your function to `this`.

Change your code to something like this.

```
class Menu extends Component {
 constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  // bind the handler
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

 // you should define your function here
 handleClick() {
 ...
 }

 render(){
 .....
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help !!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use the internal state of your component to menage the menu instead of `ref`

```
    class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(function(prevState){
            return {isOpen: !prevState.isOpen}
        });
        // Passing in a function into setState instead of an object will give you a reliable value for your component’s state and props.
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <Grid fluid>
                <div className="menuContent">
                    <Row center="xs">
                        <Col xs={12}>
                            <span href="" className="button" onClick={handleClick}>Hello, world!</span>
                            <MobileContent isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

class MobileContent extends Component {

  render() {
    if (this.props.isOpen) {
        return (
            <Grid fluid>
                <div className="mobileContent" ref="mobileContent1">
                <Row center="xs">
                    <Col xs={12}>
                    <span className="button">Hello, world!</span>
                    <span className="close">X</span>              
                    </Col>                 
                </Row>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

export default MobileContent;
```

Basically use the `state` to check if you need to render something or not. This is just the basic, you can do whatever you want with it: adding animations, reorganize you code etc...

In React the data flows fdown and a component may choose to pass its state down as props to its child components.

You have to think in React and not in jQuery way. Check this page out: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey !! thanks for the help, im tring to understand !! i still get   "this is undefined" !! Thanks

Comment: Ops my bad. I left the handleClick function inside the render function. You need to take it out and bind it. Sorry, I should have tested it. I've updated my code @HugoSeleiro

Comment: I get it work !! thanks, so i marked the answer bellow as right, because you help me understant the logic, but he help me solve the problem whit this. Thanks !!! :D

Comment: ahahah !! sorry :P